# Which terminal emulation is used?

Tags: python, terminal

I'm developing a terminal application in python.

I found out that different terminal emulators behave differently, which makes my work much harder...

I would like to account for different terminal behaviours in my code.

How can I determine reliably which terminal emulator (xterm, gnome-terminal, qtterminal, etc..) is being used?

Comment: how about checking the $TERM environment variable?

Comment: I checked it for several terminals, all but one returned the same value: "xterm".